# Duda con consulta WHERE con criterio IN en Typescript

Tags: typescript, express

Como pueden ver, tengo un controlador que trae los valores de los productos entre un precio mínimo y máximo

```
public async getProductbyPrice(req: Request, res: Response) : Promise<void>{
        const { price_min, price_max } = req.params;
        const data = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM products WHERE price BETWEEN ? AND ?;', [price_min, price_max]);
        if (data.length)
            res.json(data[0]);
        else
            res.status(404).json({ res: 'not found' });

    }
```

Al llamar a la ruta y darle esos valores, me devuelve dichos elementos en formato Json.

```
let URI = '/example/products';
this.router.get(`${URI}/:price_min&:price_max`, productController.getProductbyPrice);
```

Mi consulta va al hacer otro tipo de consulta, por ejemplo: `SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN(1,2,3)` y quiero pasar los valores a través de la ruta para que el controlador haga su trabajo. Entonces cómo declaro el array de ids tanto en el controlador y en la ruta?

Comment: podrías enviarlos separados por comas y le haces split

Comment: enviarlos de donde? en la ruta o en el controlador?